# Ios chrome getting error getUserMedia is not implemented in this browser?

Tags: ios, iphone, getusermedia, ios12

```
window.navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true }).then(function (stream) {
  console.log(stream)
}).catch(function (err) {
    console.error(err);
});
```

It's working fine in the latest ios 15 OS but it's not working old ios 12,13,14 os. Also working safari in every ios os.

Comment: Apple is late and slow adopting WebRTC, of which getUserMedia is a part. You'll have these version-compatibility problems. Sad but true.

Comment: Yes, I know but any solution for this?